# remove numbers after decimal c#

Tags: c#, decimal

I'm trying to write code to display money in unity but I'm trying to remove all the numbers after a decimal except for 1 after a decimal so it should display "34.4" but it does display "34.454"

this it the actual game view and inspector of it
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6CNb.png

this is all the code

any and all help would be great

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Money : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MoneyValue;
    public Text MoneyTextDisplay;
    private float MoneyDigit;
    void Start()    
    {



    }

    void Update()
    {
        
        MoneyDigit = Mathf.Floor(Mathf.Log10(MoneyValue) + 1);
     
        if (MoneyDigit <4)
        {
            MoneyTextDisplay.text = "Money: " + MoneyValue;
        }
        if (MoneyDigit > 3 && MoneyDigit < 7)
        {
            MoneyTextDisplay.text = "Money: " + MoneyValue / 1000  + "K";
        }
        


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for not using the decimal type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example you are looking to truncate the number and not round it.
To truncate like so you need to apply a small formula

```
var truncatedNumber =  Math.Floor(MoneyValue * 10f) / 10f;
```

multiplying by 10 will change the `34.454` into `344.54`. Then `Math.Floor` remove the extra decimal so you number become `344` and finally divide by 10 and the result become `34.4`

Answer (score 1):

When you concatenate a number to a string, the compiler inserts a call to `ToString()` on the number to get a string out of it, and then concatenates the two resulting strings.

Numbers however provide custom formatting options you can access yourself if you wish, such as:

```
MoneyTextDisplay.text = $"Money: {MoneyValue / 1000:0.0}K";
```

In this case, `0.0` means you always want to see exactly one decimal. `0.#` means you want to see at most one decimal, but no decimals if it would be 0. Use whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Use math.floor();. That will remove all the decimals. Multiply your original number by ten, floor it, then divide it by ten.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void Update()
{
    MoneyDigit = Mathf.Floor(Mathf.Log10(MoneyValue) + 1);
    if (MoneyDigit <4)
    {
        MoneyTextDisplay.text = "Money: " + MoneyValue.ToString("0.00");
    }
    if (MoneyDigit > 3 && MoneyDigit < 7)
    {
        MoneyTextDisplay.text = "Money: " + (MoneyValue / 1000).ToString("0.0") + "K";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string formatting. I'll show "N1" as the format, but you can change that to use other [numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).

```
        if (MoneyDigit <4)
        {
            MoneyTextDisplay.text = $"Money: {MoneyValue:N1}";
        }
        if (MoneyDigit > 3 && MoneyDigit < 7)
        {
            MoneyTextDisplay.text = $"Money: {MoneyValue / 1000:N1}K";
        }
```

As a side note, you may want to use the `decimal` type instead of float, because it was designed for use with things like money, where you wouldn't want to have floating-point data losses.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is using .ToString(string) method like this (.ToString("F1")):

```
decimal dec = 12.127565746m;
Console.WriteLine(dec.ToString("F1"));
```

The output of this code is 12.1

F1 means one digit after the '.'
For example, you can use F3 for three digits. (outputs 12.127)